# Setting up a mysql script to mysql dump

Tags: mysql, rsync

I'm following this tutorial - http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-create-a-server-failover-solution/  and I've done all of it successfully, there was just one bit in the comments that I need assistance with.

I'm running a woocommerce wordpress site with an rsync and mysql dump to another server (Server B)

Once Primary Server A has failed over to Secondary Server it can act like a normal server, until a service called DNSmadeeasy checks the primary is back online and switches back to that.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me write a script to copy the data back over once the primary database is back up. I need to do this because once the server has failed over, and someone places an order, the secondary server then has the most up to date copy of the database. A simple mysql dump would work to transfer the contents of Database B back onto the Database A.

At the moment i've tried to draw a diagram but can't seem to get it to work - Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at replication technology for your database solution.

Comment: If i setup a master - slave setup, and the master goes down, when the data is written to the slave, does the slave rewrite the commands it's been given once the master is back up?

Comment: You can promote a slave to a master, but also you may investigate master-master.

Comment: I cant do master-master because one is on a shared hosting environment. I need to look into writing a script which copies the data back over once the primary is back up. Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout [sja](https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/SJA_Parameters_for_command_line_for_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm). We used to use that at a place I worked years back.